# Shutter is using big memory

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, startup, memory, shutter

I included Shutter on my Startup Applications list upon installing the app. For the second time in two days, my laptop would suddenly freeze heavily for a few seconds that I can't even move the mouse pointer immediately. I had checked my system monitory --> processes, and to my surprise Shutter was using a big chunk of my memory 2.1GB out of my 3.8GB total memory so I had to end the app. Kindly note I was not using Shutter at the time of the freeze.

It seems like including it on my startup applications list is a factor in this problem. Is there a way to solve this without having to give it up on startup apps list?

I'm using 12.04 64-bit on my ThinkPad R61i. (if this would help)

Comment: You could try starting Shutter with a delay.

Comment: Thank you. May I know how to do that?

Comment: @RobinJ - I am having this issue too. Why would this help?

Comment: definitely a bug, anyone filed yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try starting Shutter with a delay.

1. Go the the startup applications dialog, choose *Shutter* and hit *Edit*.
2. Put `sleep 8s &&` before the value in the *Command* field.
3. Hit *Save*.

[image: Using ScreenCloud in this example, as I stopped using Shutter]

---

I'm using *ScreenCloud* in this example because I don't have *Shutter* in my startup applications.

Comment: Thank you, I was using "shutter --min_at_startup" as the command, but hopefully the delay would work better. I'll get back to this post in two days' time and see if I get big memory usage again or not.

Comment: Thank you for this. I haven't experienced the lagging since I used the command.

Comment: Why would this affect memory usage? I would like to understand the logic behind it. Thanks

Comment: @ElijahLynn Because when you log into your system, all applications are starting at the same time and using lots of memory. By first letting all the necessary applications like Unity and Nautilus start, and only when those have been started start launching applications like Shutter, the memory usage is divided ~eavenly. Look at it as 5 people who want to get through a door. They can either smash into each other trying to get through the door all at once, or form a line and walk through one by one.

Comment: Thanks RobinJ, that seems very inefficient. Does Linux really work like that?

Comment: @ElijahLynn Every OS does. It's not inefficient as long as developers optimise their applications properly :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since the title of this question is about shutter memory usage, I'll add my 2¢:

I use shutter heavily. After noticing huge memory usage, like 4GB or more, I tried restarting, but the usage always came back.

Then I noticed that it has the notion of a **session** -- you may need to periodically click **`File -> Close All`**, then restart (e.g. **`File -> Quit`**, reopen), to clear up the memory usage.

Maybe this is obvious to some, but the other screencap programs I've used don't have the notion of a persistent session, so this caught me off guard.